# Sympy Eq() behaviour and Sympy general usage

Tags: python, sympy, equation

In sympys `Eq(lhs,rhs)` one can instantiate an equation. However I am really really wonderin about it's behaviour and would like to ask how this equation 
type is intended to be used!

The reason I'm asking is that in Maple one uses Equations (`lhs == rhs`) there as the standard tool. However, I've seen many scripts in sympy using `x= y+z` where `x` is a python variable and thus code, and only the expression `y+z` is actual mathematics to sympy. This has consequences for the following examples:

MWE:

```
t = S('t')
f = Function('f')(t)
g = Function('g')(t)

equation = Eq(f,g+1)
equation2 = equation-1
equation3 = equation.diff(t)
equation4 = equation.subs(equation) # this I can do with subs(*equation.args)
```

All of the above yield unexpected results: The first one gives an equation in brackets minus 1, which is really weird. The differentiation only acts on the lhs, which is quite misleading imho. The subsitution yields an error, only the commented line works. This last one is ok for me, knowing that I can make it work. However, are there any more useful notations for 1 and 2 other than doing everything manually, like:

```
eq2 = Eq( equation.lhs.difft(t), equation.rhs.diff(t) )
```

In comparison Maple can substitute, derive and add equations in a mathematical sense (both sides need to be addressed).

I would be glad for any input on how to work "properly" in sympy. For the time being it seems like working with rhs-expressions only seems to be the way to go and `Eq` is a "sideproject". Thanks for every input on this one!

Comment: Most of the examples in this list of `Eq` uses involve either a `solver` or `assert`.  https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/52232/sympy.Eq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly by the time of writing (Sympy 1.10.1) there seems to be no equation class or function that represents an equation as used in mathematics. Tutorials and the documentation work with the hack `x=y` to be `x-y=0` and always use `0` as the left-hand-side. Eq() is equality, I get that, but a functioning equation is missing.

The problem with equating everything to zero is that you cannot divide easily, also if you want to substitute equations you need to manually assure, that you reformulate the variable correctly so that the "to be replaced" variable is expressed and does not appear in the python variable anymore. Even the [documentation of subs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) does not mention the standard case of substituting a mathematical expression (or simpler yet variable) from another equation that contains (expresses) this variable.

I am pretty sure that everybody learned the manipulation of equations at school and university and I am aware that all mathematical papers are written this way. Therefore I would much prefer having this widely accepted approach available in a computer algebra system. After all I have experienced algebra as the manipulation of equations.

Answer (score 1):

In an `isympy` session:

```
In [3]: t = S('t') 
   ...: f = Function('f')(t) 
   ...: g = Function('g')(t)                                                         

In [4]: equation = Eq(f, g+1)                                                        

In [5]: equation                                                                     
Out[5]: f(t) = g(t) + 1
```

The `type(equation)` is `sympy.core.relational.Equality`.

The `=` in the `Out[5]` is not related to the python `=` in `In[4]` line.

```
In [6]: equation2 = equation-1                                                       

In [7]: equation2                                                                    
Out[7]: -1 + (f(t) = g(t) + 1)
```

Here the `type` is different: `sympy.core.add.Add`

```
In [8]: equation3 = equation.diff(t)                                                 

In [9]: equation3                                                                    
Out[9]: 
d                  
──(f(t) = g(t) + 1)
dt
```

This is a `sympy.core.function.Derivative`.  It looks like an unevaluated derivative, applying to the whole `equation` object.

The error in the `subs` expression is just a misuse of `subs`.  Why are you trying to use `equation` as the argument to the method?

```
In [10]: equation4 = equation.subs(equation)                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b6a4334b7078> in <module>
----> 1 equation4 = equation.subs(equation)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/core/basic.py in subs(self, *args, **kwargs)
    865                    When a single argument is passed to subs
    866                    it should be a dictionary of old: new pairs or an iterable
--> 867                    of (old, new) tuples."""))
    868         elif len(args) == 2:
    869             sequence = [args]

ValueError: 
When a single argument is passed to subs it should be a dictionary of
old: new pairs or an iterable of (old, new) tuples.
```

Proper use of `subs`:

```
In [15]: equation4 = equation.subs([(t,t*2)])                                        

In [16]: equation4                                                                   
Out[16]: f(2⋅t) = g(2⋅t) + 1
```

====

Reference for `Eq`:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=eq#sympy.core.relational.Equality

I'm still working my way through `sympy` documentation, but it doesn't look to me like `Eq` creates an `equation` in the usual algebraic sense.  It's more of a test between two objects, that evaluates to True or False, or remains unevaluated.

By replacing `f` with `g`, we get relation that can be evaluated:

```
In [26]: equation.subs([(f,g)])    # or subs(f,g)                                                  
Out[26]: False
```

The same subs in `equation2` and `equation3` produces an error (can't add number and `False`) or the derivative of `False`.  That is the substitution is done in the `equation` part, evaluating to `False`, and the reset of the expression acts (or doesn't).

Your use of `*equation.args` fits this pattern:

```
In [43]: equation.args                                                               
Out[43]: (f(t), g(t) + 1)

In [44]: equation.subs(*equation.args)                                               
Out[44]: True
```

===

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html
suggests an alternative to `Eq(x,y)` is `x-y`:

```
In [31]: eq1 = f - (g+1)                                                             

In [32]: eq1-1                                                                       
Out[32]: f(t) - g(t) - 2

In [33]: eq1.diff(t)                                                                 
Out[33]: 
d          d       
──(f(t)) - ──(g(t))
dt         dt      

In [41]: equation.subs([(f,g)])                                                      
Out[41]: False

In [42]: equation.subs([(f,g+1)])                                                    
Out[42]: True
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. However, this I already knew, other than there's an `equation`. This is really really unfortunate. Why would an equation be a comparison, rather than an equation?! To me this is definitely a major design flaw. And no, x-y=0 is not an adequate replacement for having equations! If you would substitute this, you need to make double sure to do it right. Same for subs(equation) istn't that logic - why do you even have to ask why I want to subs this?

Comment: I can imagine a sympy class that would apply an operation to lhs and rhs.  Eq isn't that.

Comment: From the link you provided:

"If you want to do x=y, use Eq(x, y) for equality. Alternatively, all expressions are assumed to equal zero, so you can just subtract one side and use x - y."

Yeah, sadly there seems to be no such thing as a mathematical equation. How practical for a symbolic mathematics library :-/